# Unable to get 2 values using distinct

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created a product slider that is working with banner id and category i want to call category but not the duplicates one i tried to do using distinct but it's not working out for me

here is what i used

```
<?php     
$cat_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT category,bid FROM banners WHERE category != 'None'");
?>
```

but still i am getting duplicates records can anyone help me out as i want too get bid and category as well both

Comment: So what do you want to get when you have category A twice but with different bid values. Which of the two bid values you want to get, if you only want one result?

Comment: twice and with different bid values like food bid =>1 food bid=> 2

Comment: So when you say you get duplicates you actually mean both values are the same in the two output records? If so, did you check for little differences in the categories, like ending spaces and such?

Comment: yes the purpose is we add banners and relates to the category but banners are in slider so 1 slider with multi images but when i call it comes up with looping those images seperately so t stop that i have to call disctinct category

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please give example data and what output you expect from the SQL based on that example data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can get Distinct Categories with bid. You should either use Distinct Categories alone or sort your data based on required bid.